# PySpark read from S3 with defined schema

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, schema

I am trying to read a S3 file in PySpark with a defined schema as below

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, IntegerType, StringType, DoubleType

schema = StructType() \
.add('region_id', IntegerType(), True) \
.add('marketplace_id', IntegerType(), True) \
.add('merchant_customer_id', IntegerType(), True)

df_with_schema = spark.read.format("csv") \
      .option("header", True) \
      .schema(schema) \
      .load("s3a://mybucket/myfile.csv")
```

Read operation was successful but when I print the dataframe it is showing None values in place of actual data

```
[Row(region_id=None, marketplace_id=None, merchant_customer_id=None)]
```

However following code without the schema returns expected value

```
df = spark.read.options(delimiter='\t', header=False).csv("s3a://mybucket/myfile.csv")

[Row(_c0='1', _c1='1', _c2='1126044376')]
```

How can I read a file from S3 with schema defined?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with `"s3selectCSV"`:

```
spark
  .read
  .format("s3selectCSV") // "s3selectJson" for Json
  .schema(...) // optional, but recommended
  .options(...) // optional
  .load("s3://path/to/my/datafiles")
```

Doc [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-s3select.html).